# A list of all authentic games that have happened so far

Tags: database

I am looking for a database of chess games for a research purpose. I found that chessgames.com is one such site where the data for games of strong players would be available (I don't expect it to be free of course!). However, I am not at all interested in the actual moves made in a particular game; I simply want a list of two players and a result of the game. Does anybody know how and where such data would be available? It would be great if the data spans over several centuriesa as chessgames.com has.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the database need be down-loadable in some form

Comment: I don't understand why can't you just take a mega database such as the one from Chessbase and strip off everything but the names of the players. A simple scripting will be sufficient.

Comment: Precisely that is what I want to do but I don't know how to do that. Can you show me a path forward? Thanks

Comment: No database will ever have ALL authentic games so far.  And just what makes a game authentic anyway?

Comment: what makes a game 'authentic'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any such database that only gives your names and results. But there are some mega databases you can download and script to anything that you want.

- http://shop.chessbase.com/en/products/mega_database_2015
- http://www.top-5000.nl/pgn.htm
- 365chess.com
- http://ficsgames.org
- net-chess.com (where you can download correspondence games)

and others.

All you have to do is simply take a PGN file and script off the names of the players

```
[Date "1992.11.04"]
[Round "29"]
[White "Fischer, Robert J."]
[Black "Spassky, Boris V."]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]
```

In this example, you'll just need to look for "White", "Black" and "Result". This is not a very hard scripting problem, you can even do it with unix commands. If you don't know how to write a script, please consult online documentation or post a question to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can script to throw away unimportant parts of the games. What I really need is a single database which I can download instead of spending time downloading many databases.

Comment: There is no one-off database that has all the games ever recorded. Chess base's mega-database is the most complete in the list. chessgames only just you master games. At the end of the day, you might need to join the games into one single gigantic database yourself.

Comment: The chessbase database seems cool since it has so many games that it is close to complete, though I need to pay a big amount.

Answer (score 1):

There's no one singular database with all games recorded- it is fairly simple to see this is impossible. Say, a top player played a casual game against their second or trainer, perhaps for training purposes or to test out an opening variation or something. We may record the moves for our future analysis, but would it end up in any databases? No, because we would not want to reveal any information to possible opponents.

You can, however, get very big databases - SmallChess made an excellent post but I would add [CaissaBase](http://caissabase.co.uk/) to the list.

Probably, if you get all of the databases suggested and combine them (using a script to remove duplicates etc), you would have a very good and large record of pretty much any game that would make its way to the public/be in a database.